# Apache Airflow - DAG registers as success even when critical tasks fail

Tags: python, etl, pipeline, airflow

I am new to Apache Airflow and I would like to write a DAG to move some data from a set of tables in a source database to a set of tables in a target database. I am attempting to engineer the DAG such that someone can simply write the `create table` and `insert into` SQL scripts for a new source table --> target table process and drop them into folders. Then, on the next DAG run, the DAG would pick up the scripts from the folders and run the new tasks. I set up my DAG like:

```
source_data_check_task_1 (Check Operator or ValueCheckOperator)
source_data_check_task_2 (Check Operator or ValueCheckOperator, Trigger on ALL_SUCCESS)
source_data_check_task_3 (Check Operator or ValueCheckOperator, Trigger on ALL_SUCCESS)

source_data_check_task_1 >> source_data_check_task_2 >> source_data_check_task_3

for tbl_name in tbl_name_list:
    tbl_exists_check (Check Operator, trigger on ALL_SUCCESS): check if `new_tbl` exists in database by querying `information_schema`
        tbl_create_task (SQL Operator, trigger on ALL_FAILED): run the `create table` SQL script
    tbl_insert_task (SQL Operator ,trigger on ONE_SUCCESS): run the `insert into` SQL script

    source_data_check_task_3 >> tbl_exists_check
    tbl_exists_check >> tbl_create_task
    tbl_exists_check >> tbl_insert_task
    tbl_create_task >> tbl_insert)task
```

I am running into two problems with this setup: (1) If any data quality check task fails, the `tbl_create_task` still kicks off because it triggers on `ALL_FAILED` and (2) No matter which tasks fail, the DAG shows that the run was a `SUCCESS`. This is fine if the `tbl_exists_check` fails, because it's supposed to fail at least once, but not ideal if some critical task fails (like any data quality check tasks).

Is there a way to set up my DAG differently to address these problems?

Actual code below:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from airflow.operators.check_operator import ValueCheckOperator, CheckOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

sql_path = Variable.get('sql_path')

default_args = {
    'owner': 'enmyj',
    'depends_on_past':True,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0
}

dag = DAG(
    'test', 
    default_args=default_args, 
    schedule_interval=None,
    template_searchpath=sql_path
)

# check number of weeks in bill pay (made up example)
check_one = CheckOperator(
    task_id='check_one',
    conn_id='conn_name',
    sql="""select count(distinct field) from dbo.table having count(distinct field) >= 4 """,
    dag=dag
)

check_two = CheckOperator(
    task_id='check_two',
    conn_id='conn_name',
    sql="""select count(distinct field) from dbo.table having count(distinct field) <= 100""",
    dag=dag
)

check_one >> check_two

ls = ['foo','bar','baz','quz','apple']
for tbl_name in ls:
    exists = CheckOperator(
        task_id='tbl_exists_{}'.format(tbl_name),
        conn_id='conn_name',
        sql =""" select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'test' and table_name = '{}' """.format(tbl_name),
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS,
        depends_on_past=True,
        dag = dag
    )

    create = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='tbl_create_{}'.format(tbl_name),
        postgres_conn_id='conn_name',
        database='triforcedb',
        sql = 'create table test.{} (like dbo.source)'.format(tbl_name), # will be read from SQL file
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
        depends_on_past=True,
        dag = dag
    )

    insert = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='tbl_insert_{}'.format(tbl_name),
        postgres_conn_id='conn_name',
        database='triforcedb',
        sql = 'insert into test.{} (select * from dbo.source limit 10)'.format(tbl_name), # will be read from SQL file
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
        depends_on_past=True,
        dag = dag
    )

    check_two >> exists
    exists >> create
    create >> insert
    exists >> insert
```

Comment: How about changing the trigger rule to `ALL_SUCCESS` then if the upstream task fails then it will not kick off. Also if something goes wrong logically then you have to raise the `AirflowException` in order to tell Airflow to mark the task as failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a perfect use case for leveraging the [BranchPythonOperator](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html?highlight=branch#airflow.operators.BranchPythonOperator) which will allow you to perform a check to see if the table exist and then either proceed with creating the table before inserting to that table without having to worry about TRIGGER_RULES and make your DAG logic much more clear from the UI.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I implemented the `BranchPythonOperator` in place of `exists` above, so now it looks like: `tbl_exists >> create >> insert` and `tbl_exists >> dummy >> insert`. However, I had to use trigger rule `ONE_SUCCESS` on `insert` to make the process work properly. The problem with this setup is that if `check_two` fails, `tbl_exists`, `create`, and `dummy` are listed as `upstream_failed`, but `insert` is listed as `skipped` which causes the DAG to register as `SUCCESS` instead of `FAILED`. Any ideas how to avoid this? I can post full, updated code if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code I ended up with. This solution solves my two problems above:
1. It doesn't trigger the `tbl_create` task if an upstream tasks fail
2. The DAG registers as `FAILED` if any of the `check` tasks fail. 
I feel as though this solution is a little messy and would love suggestions for improvement or ways to make it more "Airflow"

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from airflow.operators.check_operator import ValueCheckOperator, CheckOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.hooks.postgres_hook import PostgresHook

sql_path = Variable.get('sql_path')

default_args = {
    'owner': 'enmyj',
    'depends_on_past':False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0
}

dag = DAG(
    'test', 
    default_args=default_args, 
    schedule_interval=None,
    template_searchpath=sql_path
)

# check number of weeks in bill pay (made up example)
check_one = CheckOperator(
    task_id='check_one',
    conn_id='conn_id',
    sql="""select count(distinct field) from dbo.table having count(distinct field) >= 4 """,
    dag=dag
)

def check_two_func():
    p = Hook('conn_id')
    sql="""select count(distinct field) from dbo.table having count(distinct field) <= 100"""
    count = p.get_records(sql)[0][0]
    if count == 0: 
        return 'dummy_fail'
    else:
        return 'dummy_success'


check_two = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id = 'check_two',
    python_callable = check_two_func,
    dag=dag
)

dummy_fail = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_fail',dag=dag)
dummy_success = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_success',dag=dag)
join = DummyOperator(task_id='join',dag=dag)

check_one >> check_two
check_two >> dummy_fail
check_two >> dummy_success

ls = ['foo','bar','baz','quz','apple']
for tbl_name in ls:
    def has_table(tbl_name=tbl_name):
        p = PostgresHook('conn_id')
        sql =""" select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'test' and table_name = '{}' """.format(tbl_name)
        count = p.get_records(sql)[0][0] #unpack the list/tuple

        # If the query didn't return rows, branch to create table
        # otherwise, branch to dummy
        if count == 0:
            return 'tbl_create_{}'.format(tbl_name)
        else:
            return 'dummy_{}'.format(tbl_name) 

    exists = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='tbl_exists_{}'.format(tbl_name),
        python_callable=has_table,
        depends_on_past=False,
        dag=dag
    )

    create = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='tbl_create_{}'.format(tbl_name),
        postgres_conn_id='conn_id',
        database='database_name',
        sql = 'create table test.{} (like dbo.source)'.format(tbl_name), # will be read from SQL file
        dag = dag
    )

    insert = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='tbl_insert_{}'.format(tbl_name),
        postgres_conn_id='conn_id',
        database='database_name',
        sql = 'insert into test.{} (select * from dbo.source limit 10)'.format(tbl_name), # will be read from SQL file
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
        dag = dag
    )

    dummy_success >> exists
    exists >> create >> insert 
    exists >> dummy >> insert
    insert >> join
```